# Generate matrix with std::generate

Tags: c++, c++11, std

Using [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/). The behavior of std::generate should be equivalent to:

```
template <class ForwardIterator, class Generator>
  void generate ( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Generator gen )
{
  while (first != last) {
    *first = gen();
    ++first;
  }
}
```

But when I try to fill matrix with 0-99 numbers. Instead I get 10 rows of 0-9. Why is that?

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > m;

#ifdef GENERATE
    struct Generator{
        int seq;
        Generator():seq(0){};
        int operator()(){return seq++;};
    } generator;
#elif defined FOR_EACH
    int i = 0;
    auto increment = [&i](int &a){a = i++;};
#endif

int x = 10, y = 10;
m.resize(x);
for(auto &v : m)
{
    v.resize(y);
    #ifdef GENERATE
        generate(begin(v), end(v), generator);
    #elif defined FOR_EACH
        for_each(begin(v),end(v), increment);
    #endif
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may also use [std::ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) to prevent copying of Generator object:

```
generate(begin(v), end(v), std::ref(generator));
```

Answer (score 2):

Because your generator is copied according to the signature

```
void generate ( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Generator gen )
                                                  copied ----^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

i.e. you keep your own copy, `std::generate` does as well. Every time you pass your own, thus unmodified `generator` into `std::generate`, i.e. each time you begin with a version that has its counter `0`.

You need to somehow preserve the counter in your functor and share it across uses of `Generator`, e.g.

```
struct Generator{
    int *seq;
    Generator(int &seq):seq(&seq){};
    int operator()(){return (*seq)++;};
};

....

int seq = 0;
generate(begin(v), end(v), Generator(seq));
```

or equivalently

```
int seq = 0;
generate(begin(v), end(v), [&seq]() { return seq++; });
```

Comment: Thanks it works :) but... after 2 changes: int operator()(){return (*seq)++;};  and generate(begin(v), end(v), Generator(seq)); Couldn't edit Your post with under 6 chars :P

Answer (score 2):

If case of `std::for_each`, you pass the lambda function `increment` which takes the automatic variable `int i = 0;` by reference. For every invocation `for_each` it creates a new `increment` functor, but `i` is not reset but just incremented; hence you see the values being continuous. The memory of the lambda function (`i`) is outside its own domain i.e. in the parent function main.

In case of your own `generate` function, the resource is within the structure i.e. `Generator::seq` is reinitialized. For every invocation of `generate`, a new Generator is created; its constructor initializes `seq` to 0, there by resetting the count every time.

```
#ifdef GENERATE
int i = 0;       // lives in main
struct Generator {
    int &seq;
    Generator(int &i):seq(i) { }
    int operator()() { return seq++; }
} generator(i);
#else
```

This should work, since the memory part of the Generator is now at a higher level.